# OpenBUGS error messages:Expected the collection operator c

Tags: bayesian, winbugs, winbugs14

I could not get the code below to work. it is a hierarchical one way ANOVA model, but when I click data load the error message that appears is expected the collection operator c. What does that mean? Can anyone please help me work the code below please? My data set is bigger, but to simplify the question I am only working here with season=4 (number of groups) and n=5 (number of subjects in each group).

```
model{
for(i in 1:n){
    Length[i] ~ dnorm(mu.l[i], tau[1]) 
    mu.l[i] <- alpha[j[i]]
}
for (p in 1:J){
    alpha[p]~dnorm(mu, tau[2])
}
mu~dnorm(0,0.0001)
for(k in 1:2){
    tau[k]<-pow(sigma[k],-2)
    sigma[k]~dunif( 0, 10)
}
}

#initials    
list( ort=1.0, alpha=c(NA, 0,0,0), tau=c(1 ,1))  

#Data
list(n=5, j=4)  
j[] length[]  
1   17.00
1   17.50
1   17.50
1   16.20
1   18.00
2   13.70
2   17.4
2   17.70
2   16.40
2   17.70
3   16.4
3   15.00
3   19.60
3   14.70
3   18.00
4   18.20
4   13.60
4   17.30
4   17.3
4   14.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few problems in your code.

1. In your model you have `J` and `Length`. In your data you have `j` (twice) and `length`, i.e. no `Length` or `J`.
2. In your initial values you have `ort` which is not a parameter used anywhere in the model and `tau` which is not stochastic (perhaps you mean `sigma`?).

Your model above should work with the following (whether it is the model you want or not is for you to decide):

```
#Initials
list( alpha=c(NA, 0,0,0))  

#Data
list(n=5, J=4, j=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4), Length=c(17,17.5,17.5,16.2,18,13.7,17.4,17.7,16.4,17.7,16.4,15,19.6,14.7,18,18.2,13.6,17.3,17.3,14.5))
```

Comment: Thanks gjabel. Sorry for mistyping of code. Problems you mentioned because of lost of translation from turkish :) I changed model as you recommend. And it's work good.

Comment: @gjabel  can you please see this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58810405/writing-conditional-distribution-in-the-winbugs-using-r2winbugs-package-in-r